# Not able to grab value for a key when using Moq on IMemoryCache

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

This is the Service that i am mocking so i am looking to test `GetTaskModel` where if i create an entry into the mocked memory cache using `CreateEntry`. That entry can be found by `GetTaskModel` which is using `TryGetValue`. But the problem is `TryGetValue` is returning null and not able to find my entry.

```
public class BackgroundTaskTrackerService : IBackgroundTaskTrackerService
{
    private const int CacheExpirationMin = 10;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public BackgroundTaskTrackerService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetTaskModel<T>(string taskId, bool removeModel = false) where T : class
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(taskId))
        {
            if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(taskId, out var model))
            {
                if (removeModel)
                {
                    _memoryCache.Remove(taskId);
                }

                return await Task.FromResult(model as T);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void SetTaskModel<T>(string taskId, T model) where T : class
    {
        _memoryCache.Set(taskId, model, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(CacheExpirationMin));
    }
}
```

And this is my test method which is creating an entry and try to assert that `GetTaskModel` is able to get that entry.

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetTaskModel_GivenTask_ReturnsTask()
    {
        //Arrange
        var task = CreateBackgroundTaskTrackerService();
        var expectedKey = "expectedKey";
        object expectedValue = "expectedValue";

        _memoryCacheMock
            .Setup(mc => mc.CreateEntry(It.IsAny<object>()))
            .Returns(_mockCacheEntry.Object);

        object expectedModel = null;
        var memoryCache = GetMemoryCache(expectedModel);
        memoryCache.Set(expectedKey, expectedValue);

        //Act
        var result = task.GetTaskModel<Task<It.IsAnyType>>(expectedKey);

        //Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result.Result);
        Assert.Equal(expectedModel, result.Result);
    }
```

and test is using this fucntion

```
 public IMemoryCache GetMemoryCache(object expectedValue)
    {
        _memoryCacheMock
            .Setup(x => x.TryGetValue(It.IsAny<object>(), out expectedValue))
            .Returns(true);
        return _memoryCacheMock.Object;
    }
```

I am not sure why i am not able to find the task set by `Set` method using `GetTaskModel`. It's giving me null for the first Assert. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are making things very complicated, you use async while there is really nothing async about it.

Comment: You setup TryGetValue to use expectedValue as out parameter and return true. And you have set expectedValue (via expectedModel) to null so it will return null as you wished. Set expectedValue to the value you actually want to be returned. And you didn't show or have forgotten to setup the Set method for your mock.